# Get Filename from Filepath

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to get the filename from a filepath.
My problem is, that I found many solutions for handling it with input via parameters.
But I want to use a userinput instead of a parameter.

The soultion for parameters is:

```
%~nxI       //I could be number for the parameter count
```

My script actually looks like this:

```
   @echo off
   set /p path=Film: 
   echo %path2%
   pause
```

Now I want to get the filename + extension from `%path%` and write it to `%path2%`.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You do know that path is probably already used as a parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set /p x=Film:
echo %x%
for %%F in (%x%) do set q=%%~nF
echo %q%
```

...and *for Pete's sake* do not prompt the user to set the **PATH** variable! use some other variable name!

Comment: thx for the fast solution. i works great. and thx for the hint with variablename.

Comment: No problem. Another happy customer. By the way, I accept upvotes, 'accepts', cash advances, etc.

Answer (score 2):

an alternative, instead of using `FOR`, that may be useful in some situations, is to substitute the variable passing the values as parameters in a `CALL`.

```
call :extractfn %x% q
echo %q%
goto :eof
:extractfn
set %2=%~n1
goto :eof
```